# Kivy to Exe with PyInstaller. [Failed to execute script main] because of SoundLoader

Tags: python, kivy, exe, pyinstaller

Im trying to convert my .py file to .exe. Im using kivy in my .py file.I realized that getting Fatal error detected.Failed to execute script main error if i use **SoundLoader.load('test.wav')**.
main.py :

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager
class Manager(ScreenManager):
    sound = SoundLoader.load('test.wav')
    sound.play()
class testapp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Manager()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    testapp().run()
```

If i run my .py file,i get sound on windows and linux systems.I followed these steps to create my exe: [KIVY package for Windows](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/packaging-windows.html). My exe runs if i do not use SoundLoader lines. But if i add that , i can't even open console or app because this error appears.Thanks for advices.

Comment: Did you include `test.wav` in your `datas` of the spec file?

Comment: I added my .wav to datas. After that i got this error: 
**File "kivy\lib\gstplayer\_gstplayer.pyx" , line 233, in kivy.lib.gstplayer._gstplayer.GstPlayer.load kivy.lib.gstplayer._gstplayer.GstPlayerException: Unable to create a playbin.Consider setting the environment GST REGISTRY to a user accessible path, such as ~/registry.bin ... [next line:] [428]Failed to execute script main**.

Answer (score 1):

If you have same problem , Fix this lines in your **.spec** file:

```
from kivy_deps import sdl2, glew, gstreamer
...
...
datas=[('Files\test.wav','.')
...
...
*[Tree(p) for p in (sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins +  gstreamer.dep_bins)],
...
...
```

Worked for me..

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
from kivy_deps import sdl2, glew, gstreamer

datas=[(r'Assets', 'bullet.wav'),
         (r'Assets', 'music.wav'),
         (r'Assets', 'Explosion.wav')],

*[Tree(p) for p in
           (sdl2.dep_bins +
           glew.dep_bins +  gstreamer.dep_bins)],
```

Answer (score 0):

The next thing helped me:

```
python -m pip install kivy[full]
```

This overlaped prior conda installation:

```
conda install -c conda-forge kivy
```

After that mp3 file played fine.

Packages alteration after installation from pip (my dir):

• `kivy-deps.glew~=0.3.1` in `f:\pzz\lib\site-packages (from kivy[full]) (0.3.1)`

• `kivy-deps.gstreamer~=0.3.3` in `f:\pzz\lib\site-packages (from kivy[full]) (0.3.3)`